# How to plot multiple lines in one plot and save them

Tags: matlab, plot

**Question 1**  ***SOLVED***

I am working on the following simulation:

```matlab
x = [8 9 7 6 5];`
if isvector(x)
      for i=1:length(x)
          % simulation gives me a matrix y,t,z, (c by 5)
          % where size(y,1)=size(z,1)=size(t,1)= lenght(x)=5
          % size(y,2)=c
          % a plot will collect all lines:
%            for x=8 there are 3 lines ( the first row of each matrix `y`, `t`, `z`
%            for x=9 there are 3 lines ( the second row of each matrix `y`, `t`, `z`
%            ...
%            for x=5 there are 3 lines ( the 5th row of each matrix `y`, `t`, `z`
          end
end
```

Let me show an example:

```matlab
y = rand(5,8)
t = rand(5,8)
z = rand(5,8)
```

To plot I have started with:

```matlab
% I was using the initial loop:

if isvector(x)
      for i=1:length(x)
          % simulation gives me a matrix y,t,z, (c by 5)

          %% plots
          h(1)=figure;
          plot (c,y(i,:));
          grid on;
          hold on;
          plot (c,t(i,:));
          plot (c,z(i,:));
          hold off;
          end
end
```

As a result, MATLAB gives me 3 figures, but I have expected only one figure with multiple lines. I start from the inside of the initial loop and create a new loop, but it doesn't help me. How to fix it? How to plot all lines (in this example, all 15 lines (#x(i) = 5, #array = 3))?

Answer (score 1):

If you need that loop for further analysis, just move the `figure()` outside the loop. Otherwise, you could also plot all lines from a single `plot()` call:

```matlab
x = [8 9 7 6 5];
c = 1:8;
y = rand(5, 8);
t = rand(5, 8);
z = rand(5, 8);

% Loop approach, move figure() outside the loop
if isvector(x)
  figure(1);
  hold on;
  for i = 1:length(x)
    plot(c, y(i, :));
    plot(c, t(i, :));
    plot(c, z(i, :));
  end
  hold off;
  grid on;
end

% Plot everything with one plot() call
if isvector(x)
  figure(2);
  plot(c, [y; t; z]);
  grid on;
end
```

The outputs are the same except for the lines' color, which is due to the order of the plotting (first line of `y`, `t`, `z`, second line of ..., and so on vs. all lines from `y`, all lines from `t`, and so on.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** To plot all three lines for each `x(i)` in separate figures, you could use this loop approach:

```matlab
x = [8 9 7 6 5];
c = 1:8;
y = rand(5, 8);
t = rand(5, 8);
z = rand(5, 8);

if isvector(x)
  for i = 1:length(x)
    figure(i);
    hold on;
    plot(c, y(i, :));
    plot(c, t(i, :));
    plot(c, z(i, :));
    hold off;
    grid on;
  end
end
```

Comment: How to use your suggestion (1 ` % Loop approach, move figure() outside the loop`) to plot for each `x(i)`? It means I would like to get 5 plots with 3 lines. I cant add `figure(2), ...,figure(5)` It will give me an error

Comment: @user36610 In your question, you asked for all 15 lines in one plot! Nevertheless, please see the edit at the end of my answer.